# AVFoundation and Speech To Text

Tags: swift, swiftui, avfoundation, speech-to-text

I was trying out the Native iOS Speech To Text with speech recognition and it has these few lines of code to transcribe speech.

```
   Button {                            
        player.seek(to: .zero)
        player.play()

        speechRecognizer.reset()
        speechRecognizer.transcribe()
                                                                        
    } label: {
         Text("Start").font(.system(size: 16))
         .foregroundColor(.gray)
    }
```

Each time after pressing the button, the play sound using AVFoundation will not work.

Anyone with similar experiences?  Is there a way to get around this?